# How do I set the focus to the Desktop from within my C# application

Tags: c#, winforms

Winforms App.  .Net 3.5.

I need to set the focus from my C# application to the user's desktop (almost like simulating a mouse click on the desktop).

Can someone please show me how to do this with C#?  I just want to set focus on the desktop so the focus is no longer on my application but I want to do this from within my application.

Edit:  An answer below works by setting the focus to the desktop, but it minimizes all the open windows on the user's desktop.

Is there a way I can maybe set the focus to the next open window on the desktop instead?  I just want to get the focus off of my application (without minimizing my application or hiding it).  I just want to move focus to somewhere else.  Maybe the desktop was not the best choice if it will minimize all the user's open windows/applications.

Comment: Try to minimise your application.

Comment: I don't want to minimize my application or any other application that is already open on the desktop.  I just want to move focus off of my application to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this COM object in your project:

**Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation**

And then just call:

```
Shell32.ShellClass shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
shell.MinimizeAll();
```

This will minimize all the windows and then focus the desktop. Otherwise, if you have your window non-full screen then you can simulate the mouse click using:

```
//This is a replacement for Cursor.Position in WinForms
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

//This simulates a left mouse click
public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
    SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
}
```

You can calculate coordinates by looking at your window startup location plus height/width and select a available space (that will be the desktop indeed).

Comment: I don't want to minimize, I just want to move the focus to another window other than my own application window (without minimizing my application or any other application that is running)

Comment: @RandolfR-F, I don't think that using coordinates is going to the the most effective way of getting to the next window. There is API available to get the next window.

Comment: Can you please show me how to get the next window (or the name of the API to do this)?  Thanks.

Comment: @RandolfR-F:  The mouse click simulate code works, but it is kind of jarring to the user, because their mouse pointer jumps from my application all the way over to the xpos and ypos that I set in LeftMouseClick.  Is there another way to set focus somewhere else without having the mouse pointer jump across the user's screen?

Comment: @fraXis I'm sorry but that's the only hack I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you.

```
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace ConsoleApplication1 { 
class Program { 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)] 
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName); 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true)] 
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

    const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111; 
    const int MIN_ALL = 419; 
    const int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 416; 

    static void Main(string[] args) { 
        IntPtr lHwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null); 
        SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);  
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL_UNDO, IntPtr.Zero); 
    } 
} 
}
```

### Get Next Window

I don't have a code example ready for these two but I'm going to give you the links to both. The first think you need to do is call [`GetWindow`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindow.html). After doing that you'll want to call [`SwitchToThisWindow`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SwitchToThisWindow.html) passing in the pointer you received from `GetWindow`.

Comment: Thanks.  That almost does the trick, but it minimizes all the open windows on the desktop.  I just want to move the focus off of my application.  Is there a way I can set it to the next visible window on the desktop (the window that is the next in line after my application window)?

Comment: @fraXis, I edited my answer. I don't have a code sample ready for the process but I outlined it with API reference material so it should be really easy for you to build.

Comment: The "SwitchToThisWindow" page states: "Note that this function is deprecated and not intended for general use according to MSDN."  Anything else I can try?

Comment: @fraXis, sure you can try `BringWindowToTop` here http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/BringWindowToTop.html

Comment: This helped me with a similar problem, where I had a Windowless app that I didn't want receiving focus but there was the odd querk where it was. A combination of FindWindow and BringWindowToFront did it. Cheers.