# How to start a UWP app with a global shortcut through a background Win32 process?

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-bridge, full-trust

I am working on a UWP screen recorder, I need a global shortcut (keyboard hotkey) that just launches the app, so I need a background process that runs from start-up, allowing me to launch the app at any time. I don't need to perform any in-app action. I could find some tutorials about global shortcuts in uwp apps, but they refer only to in-app actions and the Win32 process doesn't run with the app closed, so I couldn't figure out how to do with my app.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a background Win32 process to launch a uwp app? When the system startup, running the Win32 process? Can you provide more details about your expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, and when I press the shortcut the process opens the app. For the future, I was thinking about making that optional, but currently I just would like to figure out how to do that and if it is possible

Comment: You could follow the tutorial @Bogdan Mitrache shared and then when click the hotkey you registered, the hotkeys_HotkeyPressed event will be triggered from the sample, you could try to launch the uwp app in it.

Comment: Yeah, that's my plan, but I don't really understand how to launch the app from there

Comment: You could try to set [Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps) in uwp app and then use `Process.Start()` method to launch it.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Stefan Wick (form MSFT) had a detailed blog post about how you can do this.

- https://stefanwick.com/2018/05/15/global-hotkey-registration-in-uwp/

As he mentions at the end of the blog post, another SO thread was the inspiration:

- [Global hotkeys in windowless .NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133656/global-hotkeys-in-windowless-net-app/17136050)

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean is a global (keyboard) shortcut (like Win + O), not a shortcut to launch it from cmd

Comment: Thank you, but I am already following the tutorial and it uses global shortcuts to perform an in-app action, while I'd like to use them to open the uwp app