# what is reverse of window.activate() function in wpf

Tags: wpf

I need to deactivate my wpf window.
This seems like reverse of `window.activate()` function in wpf.
But I couldn't find `window.deactivate()` function.
What is reverse of `window.activate()` function in wpf?

Comment: I know window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
I want to another function.

Comment: `Activate()` brings the window to the foreground and activates it. What exactly do you mean by "the reverse"? Where do you want the window to go?

Answer (score 0):

By activate another window you can deactivate your active window. For example if you have 2 window: `WinA` (MainWindow) & `WinB` and you want deactivate `WinB` you can use this code:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
```

Also you can do this by focus on desktop. To do it you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535165/how-do-i-set-the-focus-to-the-desktop-from-within-my-c-sharp-application).

Comment: thanks for your answer.
But What I want is `Application.Current.MainWindow.DeActivate();`
In c#, I can't find this function.